# 404 Error with viewing group members in JIRA REST API

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get the list of users in a group called "Core QA Team". The deprecated API works fine for me. Below is the API endpoint.

https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/group?groupname=Core%20QA%20Team&expand=users

But I keep getting below 404 response, If i try the suggested endpoint by JIRA.

https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/group/member?groupname=Core%20QA%20Team

I have tried different combination with the capitals and spacing, but no luck. Am I doing something wrong with the URL  ? I have admin privileges also, is there anything specific that it looks for ?

Response

```
<status>
<status-code>404</status-code>
 <message>
null for uri: https://jira.mydomain.com/rest/api/2/group/member?groupname=Core%20QA%20Team
</message>
</status>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version is your JIRA instance? Find the correct documentation for your version [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/). The default `GET /group` deprecation and `GET /group/member` addition is a recent change, it might be possible that your version of JIRA is too old.

EDIT:

I went through the docs.
This change is effective since **JIRA 7.1.0** so that means if your instance is < 7.1.0 you can just keep using the old `GET /group` endpoint.

Comment: Thanks! got it...  My version is older than 7.1